# Query fails Google Drive Android

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I'm using this code:

```
GoogleApiClient client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                .build();
Query query = new Query.Builder().addFilter(Filters.and(Filters.and(Filters.and(Filters.eq
                    (SearchableField.TITLE, getString(R.string.app_name)), Filters
                    .eq(SearchableField.TRASHED, false)), Filters.eq(SearchableField.PARENTS, Collections
                    .singletonList(Drive.DriveApi
                    .getRootFolder(client)
                    .getDriveId()))), Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, GoogleDriveClient.FOLDER_MIME))).build();
            DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result = Drive.DriveApi.query(client, query).await(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                client.disconnect();
                return;
            }
```

There is always an error: `Status{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}`

I enabled the Drive Api in Google Console, I checked again my SHA1 fingerprint and other operations are working. Is it allowed to perform a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a documentation for [Querying for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/queries)

> You can use the **`com.google.android.gms.drive.query`** package to
>   search a user's Drive account for files whose metadata match your
>   search criteria. You can issue a query for a specific folder or on the
>   entire filesystem.
>
> *Note: The Android Drive API only works with the **`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`** scope. This means that only files which a user has opened or created with your
>   application can be matched by a query.*

Here is an example to build queries.

> A query is created by building an instance of the [`Query`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/query/Query.html) class
>   and specifying the search criteria with [`Filters`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/query/Filters.html). The following
>   example finds all files with the title "**`HelloWorld.java`**".
>
> ```
> Query query = new Query.Builder()
>         .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "HelloWorld.java"))
>         .build();
> ```
>
> You can use the `Filters` class to build expressions. Multiple filters
>   can be joined together using the and and or methods.
>
> Once a Query object has been constructed it can be executed on the
>   entire file system using [`Drive.DriveApi`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveApi.html) as follows:
>
> ```
> Drive.DriveApi.query(googleApiClient, query);
> ```
>
> This query starts in the My Drive (the root) folder and recursively
>   traverse the entire filesystem, returning all entries matching the
>   Filters expression tree.
>
> A query can alternatively be executed only in a specific folder using
>   an instance of the [`DriveFolder`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveFolder.html) class, as shown by:
>
> ```
> DriveFolder folder= ...;
> folder.query(query);
> ```
>
> This call does not scan recursively; only direct entries in this
>   folder matching filter conditions are returned.